# Git checkout no longer warns of unchanged files

Tags: git

If I have some changes in `BranchA` and then checkout `BranchB` those files are auto merged into `BranchA`.

I used to get a warning that forced me to either commit or stash the changes:
something like: `my_file.rb would be overwritten by merge. Cannot merge.`

At some point this stopped happening.  Any thoughts?  Here's my `.getconfig`

```
[user]
        name = <my name>
        email = <my email>
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
[color]
        ui = always
        interactive = always
        diff = auto
        branch = auto
        status = auto
[color "diff"]
        new = cyan
        old = magenta
        frag = yellow
        meta = green
        commit = normal
[alias]
        co = checkout
        ci = commit
        st = status
        br = branch
        hist = log --pretty=format:\"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]\" --graph --date=short
        type = cat-file -t
        dump = cat-file -p
```

Answer (score 1):

It's only changes that you haven't commited yet that git complains about.

Comment: Yeah, its supposed to complain about the uncommitted changes.  That's what I want, but instead it just lets me do the checkout and it merges the uncommitted files in without the warning / error that most people get ( including me on my other machine )

Answer (score 0):

Update:

While answering a similar question, I realized that I had answered this same question elsewhere as well and while searching, also came across this answer that I had made sometime earlier. Below is the link to that answer, which I believe is to be the right one:

[Git branches behaving strangely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337122/git-branches-behaving-strangely/6337527#6337527)

---

Old answer:

Unless you are using `git checkout -m` or `-f` it should still be saying that.

What does `git status` tell you?

Comment: git status will show the files that haven't been changed.  I'm not using -m or -f.  I'm just doing git checkout branch_name

Comment: Sorry, files that have been changed :)